# Complex geometry and Hodge Theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I would like to know what are the prerequisites for Voisin's book (vol 1).  Would knowing the basics of algebraic topology and differential geometry be enough to start the book?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at he book by Huybrecths, if you are comfortable with everything in it; then Voisin will be doable.

Also take a look at this [Learning Complex Geometry - Textbook Recommendation Request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573610/learning-complex-geometry-textbook-recommendation-request?rq=1)